# to.JSON() in Spark Streaming using pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, pickle, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I used `toJSON()` method to convert **DataFrame** to **RDD of json** documents within `transform()` function of spark Streaming.

I am using `pyspark` for coding like follow:

```
def process(rdd):
  rddDataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
  rddback = rddDataFrame.toJSON()
return rdd

dstream_test = dstream_in.transform(lambda rdd: process(rdd))
```

But I got the following error:

> ```
>  UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'
> ```

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Also could you please provide data samples?

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass a rdd to a function, pass the function to your rdd.

Define your transformation for each row, then send it

```
def transform(row):
    ....

your_rdd = your_rdd.map(transform)
```